# GreenDAO entities with ToOne relation and Foreign Key

Tags: android, greendao, greendao-generator

I'm trying to create entities in my database using GreenDAO. My object is defined by this class:

```
public class Container {
    String id; //GUID
    String name;
    Product product;
}

public class Product {
    String urlImage;
    String productName;
    String description;
}
```

The following code is defining my entities:

```
Entity container = schema.addEntity("Container");
Property productsForeignKey = container.addStringProperty("id").notNull().unique().getProperty(); 
container.addStringProperty("name");

Entity product = schema.addEntity("Product");
product.addStringProperty("productName");
product.addStringProperty("urlImage");
product.addStringProperty("description");

containerToProduct = container.addToOne(product, productsForeignKey);
```

In the end I get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Currently only single FK columns are supported: ToOne 'product' from Container to Product
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using Container's primary key as Product's foreign key. It turns out that String Foreign Key is not a good choice. So, my solution is more like this:

```
Entity container = schema.addEntity("Container");
Property productsForeignKey = container.addLongProperty("newId").primaryKey().autoincrement().getProperty(); 
container.addStringProperty("name");

Entity product = schema.addEntity("Product");
product.addStringProperty("productName");
product.addStringProperty("urlImage");
product.addStringProperty("description");

containerToProduct = container.addToOne(product, productsForeignKey);
```

Where newId is just random field used for convenience.